# Mesh Won't Move With Armature After Setting Parent

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, parent

I know there are tons of threads about this problem, but I swear I've read them all and still can't figure this out.

I have spent the last 2 hours at least trying to figure out why my mesh wont move with my armature. This is my first time using Blender and I was loving everything about it until i got to rigging. I jumped into this program suddenly for my final project that's due tonight cause I was tired of dealing with Maya's bullshit. All my previous experience has been with Maya where rigging is done automatically for you.

I have read almost every result Google will give me about what might be the problem, and nothing has helped. I have been selecting the armature and then the mesh (and tried it the other way around a few times), and then clicking parent > armature deform > with automatic weights. It has yet to work. Seeing as I am new to blender, there could easily be something wrong with how I made my mesh.

There is also a good chance I won't know what y'all are talking about when you answer, so if I can get as much detail as possible that would be very helpful.

Any help y'all can give me would be appreciated.
My project is linked below:
In the file I have purposely removed the parent from the mesh and armature.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vZNW4INQ79oeSoSQZsmh1psc4Qz9V3sS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have flipped normals as you see if you enable the *Face Orientation* option in the *Viewport Overlays* panel:

[image]

So go in Edit mode, select all, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals*, and parent again *With Automatic Weight*.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!